# Array ( [0] => 42S02 [1] => 1146 [2] => Table 'prueba_jose.prueba_jose' doesn't exist ) -problema resuelto

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

Como están? Soy un principiante en el mundo de la programación, y he tratado de encontrar el error que tiene este código, pero no lo encuentro :c, el error que me da, es que pone el mensaje:Algo malo paso, vuelve a intentar más tarde :D!, y no encuentro por que me sale esto, :c, la conexión que esto utilizando es esta:

y lo que me da

```
print_r($query->errorInfo());
```

es este:

Array ( [0] => 42S02 [1] => 1146 [2] => Table 'prueba_jose.prueba_jose' doesn't exist )

```
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('DATABASE', 'prueba_jose');
 
try {
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
  <?php 

include('conexion.php');
//session_start();

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

$usuario = $_POST['username'];
$correo = $_POST['mail'];
$contraseña = $_POST['password'];
$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$apellido = $_POST['lastname'];
$password_hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM prueba_jose WHERE correo=:email");
$query->bindParam("email", $correo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

if ($query->fetchColumn() > 0) {
    echo '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>';
}

if ($query->fetchColumn() == 0) {
    $query = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO `prueba_jose`(`nombre`,`apellido`,`usuario`,`contra`,`correo`) VALUES (:namexd,:lastname,:username,:password_hash,:email)");
    $query->bindParam("username", $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("password_hash", $password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("email", $correo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("namexd", $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("lastname", $apellido, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result = $query->execute();

    if ($result) {
        echo '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
    } else {
         print_r($conexion->errorInfo());
        echo '<p class="error">Algo malo paso, vuelve a intentar más tarde :D!</p>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor redacta un título objetivo del problema en cuestión, lee [ask]

Comment: Podrías poner `print_r($conexion->errorInfo());` en el else del `if ($result)` para ver cuál es el error, y agregarlo a la pregunta?

Comment: No manejes la obtención de posibles errores de esa forma, pues en realidad no te va a decir cual es el problema de fondo, lee aqui como administrar ese aspecto: https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Por otro lado tampoco debes usar `rowCount()`, la propia documentación indica que debe ser [**`fetchColumn`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

Comment: braver Este es lo que me da cuando pongo el print: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: @user194761 el error completo va en la pregunta por favor

Comment: BetaM Esta bien, voy a cambiarlo por fetchColumn :D

Comment: @BetaM ya lo puse en la pregunta, srry es que es mi primeravez en stackoverflow :D

Comment: el print_r($conexion->errorInfo()); lo puse en el else :D

Comment: No debe ser sobre conexion sino sobre query así mira: `print_r($query->errorInfo());` y ya te debe sacar que error existe

Comment: Hay varias incoherencias en tu código que trataré de señalar brevemente: 1. Si la intención del `SELECT` es verificar si existen registros antes de insertar, entonces deberías hacer un conteo con algo así: **`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prueba_jose WHERE mail=:email`**, entonces sí podrás usar `fetchColumn()` a continuación; 2. Los `if` están mal organizados. Como lo tienes ahora, verificará el primero y luego el segundo. Deberías tener un `if ... else`; 3. En el `INSERT` usas una columna  `correo` y en el `SELECT` la llamas `email`, posiblemente ese sea el motivo del error; 4. Como consejo, pon ...

Comment: ... los `bindParam()` en el orden de la instrucción SQL, así es más fácil de comprobar errores; 5. Como sugieren los compañeros, verifica errores directamente sobre el objeto que los produciría, en este caso `$query`; 6. Otro consejo, evita el uso de `ñ` o acentos en nombres de variables, tablas, columnas. Si no codificas bien te van a romper el código; 7. Considera organizar mejor, por ejemplo, no hagas el hash hasta no estár seguro de que realmente habrá una inserción. Estás preparando cosas sin estar seguro de que vas a usarlas. Falta rigor en tu estilo de programar. Ya sé que eres nuevo.

Comment: Ya arregle el error :D! no tenia que poner el nombre de mi base de datos, que es prueba_jose, tenia que poner el nombre de la tabla :D, y de paso, arregle un problema que tenia en el id con el AUTO_INCREMENT en phpmyadmin :D, tomare en cuenta los consejos que me dieron, no se mucho sobre esto, solo seguía los pasos de un tutorial de una pagina web :D